# Backbone: Feed JSON in a variable instead of fetching through URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, backbone.js

We are trying to modify an existing script which uses backbone.js to fetch JSON from a URL and render it in a defined way on screen.

Earlier the script was pointing to an external PHP file to fetch the JSON from it.

```
url: function () {          
    var ajaxValue = document.getElementById('ajax').value;
    if(ajaxValue==0){
        return this.options.apiBase + '/liveEvents.json';           
    } else {
        var eventDate = document.getElementById('timestamp').value;
        return this.options.apiBase + '/ajax.php?eventDate='+eventDate;         
    }
},
```

But now we are trying to omit the requirement of PHP and get JSON purely using Javascript. For this, we created a JS function fetch_data_set(), that returns proper JSON

```
var ArrayMerge = array1.concat(array2,array3,array4);
return JSON.stringify(ArrayMerge);
```

So our question is, how can we feed this JSON to backbone instead of using an external URL. Because if we do this (which is obviously wrong):

```
 url: function () {         
    var ajaxValue = document.getElementById('ajax').value;
    if(ajaxValue==0){           
        var data_set = fetch_data_set();
        return data_set;
    } 
},
```

It throws error: Error: A "url" property or function must be specified

Answer (score 0):

The main key is to extend `Backbone.sync` instead of url() method, so you could use this way to fetch your models in any kind of model, and you could do something similar like this link:

https://github.com/huffingtonpost/backbone-fixtures/blob/master/backbone-fixtures.js

Answer (score 0):

Backbone.Model contains a `sync()` function able to load JSON data from an url. `sync()` uses the `url()` function to determine from where it should fetch data. (Note : `sync()` is called under-the-hood by `save()`, `fetch()` and `destroy()`)

The trick here is that you should stop overriding `url()` and reimplement `sync()` directly instead, cf. http://backbonejs.org/#Model-sync

Here is an example :

```
// specialized version to be used with a store.js - like object
sync: function(method, model, options) {
  console.log("sync_to_store begin('"+method+"',...) called with ", arguments);
  var when_deferred = when.defer();

  var id = this.url();

  if(method === "read") {
    if(typeof id === 'undefined')
      throw new Error("can't fetch without id !");
    var data = model.store_.get(id);
    // apply fetched data
    model.set(data);
    when_deferred.resolve( [model, undefined, options] );
  }
  else if(method === "create") {
    // use Backbone id as server id
    model.id = model.cid;
    model.store_.set(id, model.attributes);
    when_deferred.resolve( [model, undefined, options] );
  }
  else if(method === "update") {
    if(typeof id === 'undefined')
      throw new Error("can't update without id !");
    model.store_.set(id, model.attributes);
    when_deferred.resolve( [model, undefined, options] );
  }
  else if(method === "delete") {
    if(typeof id === 'undefined')
      throw new Error("can't delete without id !");
    model.store_.set(id, undefined);
    model.id = undefined;
    when_deferred.resolve( [model, undefined, options] );
  }
  else {
    // WAT ?
  }

  console.log("sync_to_store end - Current changes = ", model.changed_attributes());
  return when_deferred.promise;
}
```

- Note 1 : API is slightly different from vanilla Backbone since I return
  a when promise
- Note 2 : `url()` is still used, as an id